# PS1 not setting color

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have a PS1 varible in bash_profile file as

```
orange=$(tput setaf 166);
yellow=$(tput setaf 228);
green=$(tput setaf 71); 
white=$(tput setaf 15); 
bold=$(tput bold); 
reset=$(tput sgr0); 
PS1="\[${bold}\]"; 
PS1+="\[${orange}\]\u"; # username 
PS1+="\[${white}\]@"; 
PS1+="\[${yellow}\]\h "; # host 
PS1+="\[${green}\]\w"; # working directory 
PS1+="\[${white}\]\$ \[${reset}\]"; # '$' (and reset color) 
export PS1;
```

When I open the new terminal instance it's showing everything properly except color. 
[image: PS1 set without color - new terminal instance]

But, when I execute the command

```
source .bash_profile
```

the color is working. It disappears if I open a new tab.

[image: source .bash_profile]

But, In a new terminal instance, without executing the source command, 
the color works for

`export PS1="\[\033[35m\]\t\[\033[m\]-\[\033[36m\]\u\[\033[m\]@\[\033[32m\]\h:\[\033[33;1m\]\w\[\033[m\]\$ "`

[[image: New terminal instance - without source- new PS1 variable[3]]

What's the reason for this weird behavior?

In breif, in a new terminal session,
first PS1 is not displaying colors but the second ps1 put in the same bash_profile file is displying it. 
But the first one is displaying colors when it is sourced.

Note: I am using mac.
I m also sure that the variable is getting set in bash_profile 
but the color is not being set.

Comment: If I get it correctly, it is simple logic, if you have done changes in PROFILE(DOT profile or bash profile) if you want to see changes in same session run `source` for it OR in case you are opening new session DOT profile again gets loaded with new values and displays it too.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 ik. But, in a new session the above ps1 variable is not displaying. But it is doing when I source it. 
I need not source it for the below ps1 variable. It's working fine.

Comment: Does opening a new terminal instance load the profile? Some terminals don't do that to speed up start-up time. You need to log in again to see the difference.

Comment: What value of `PS1` *do* you get?

Comment: You say you're sure the variable is getting set in `.bash_profile`. Are you sure `.bash_profile` is being used when the terminal starts? This is not always the case.

Comment: `export PS1` isn't necessary; other programs started by your shell don't care about  its value.

Comment: @thatotherguy Yes. I can see the bashrc is running first and then the bash profile by echoing them.

Comment: In some systems `.bashrc` some have `bash_profile` too so you need to check which is getting loaded during opening up of session, check it once by putting this values one by one and you will get to know who is responsible for load.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I can see bash_profile is setting the PS1 variable in mine. Why in second PS1 variable it's showing with color? I will update it with photos.

Comment: I have updated it with images, can you pls check ? @choroba

Comment: \[\]\[\]\u\[\]@\[\]\h \[\]\w\[\]$ \[\] for first one
\[\033[35m\]\t\[\033[m\]-\[\033[36m\]\u\[\033[m\]@\[\033[32m\]\h:\[\033[33;1m\]\w\[\033[m\]$
 for second one @chepner

Comment: Yeah the problem is not with time. But in a new terminal instance or session, first PS1 is not printing colors and second is printing colors. I am not able to know the reason.

Comment: What *exactly* is in your `.bash_profile`? Nothing you've show would produce the additional output in your screen shots, which makes me think there is something else present that makes the difference.

Comment: @chepner can u pls check by pasting the same ps1 variables in your bash_profile ? I doubt, it would give you the same result.

Comment: Not on-topic here on SO, anyhow -- this is interactive shell configuration, not software development. Consider our sister site [unix.se].

Comment: @Prajwal I get a colored prompt.

Comment: @chepner for both ps1 variables?

Comment: BTW, putting `PS4=':$BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO+'; set -x` in your dotfiles to log what's going on during initialization is liable to be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had installed solarized color scheme/theme for my xterm-256 terminal. It was the one causing the issue. When I change the color scheme, the PS1 is working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You should investigate a little more (yes even more).

In each case you should use `printf "%q\n" "$PS1"` to see the exact value of the variable `PS1` (with escaped unprintable characters).  Are you just trying to *add* the colors to an already set `PS1` variable?  So, if you get the uncolored output, could that be because your code just wasn't executed so the original value is still set?  Then just the PROFILE script isn't executed.

`.bash_profile` typically only is executed when a *login*-shell is started.  Nowadays many distributions don't get it right and are full of workarounds in this matter, so they often contain `.bashrc` files which source `.bash_profile` in their beginning.  `.bashrc` is sourced for each new shell, so effectively, your `.bash_profile` might well be sourced for each shell as well.

I could guess that your `.bashrc` *first* sources `.bash_profile` and *then* sets the `PS1` to a value like yours, just without the colors.  But of course, that's guesswork.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect in the OP's case that using `~/.bashrc` rather than `~/.bash_profile` to set the colours, is all that is required.

Here is how things work:

There are a number of files involved in setting up your bash environment.

`/etc/profile`  sets the system-wide profile

`~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, `~/.profile` - These are read by default when bash is invoked as a *login* shell

`~/.bashrc` - This is always read unless bash is invoked as `sh` or bash is invoked as `bash --norc`

`~/.bash_logout` - login shell cleanup

`~/.inputrc` - readline initialisation file.

Which files, and order that these files are read depends on exactly how bash is invoked.

There are a number of cases not all of which are mutually exclusive:

- login shell
- interactive shell
- non-interactive shell
- posix mode
- bash invoked with stdin connected to network connection (yes
  it will know)
- bash invoked as `sh`
- bash is invoked with the effective uid/gid not equal to the real uid/gid

You need to be aware of which cases apply to your invocation in order to determine which files will be read.

`man bash` and search for invocation, for the exact details.